# How to Add Array ListSequential form using Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have input web cam video processing each frame 1-by-8 co-ordinates values in list.

Values are like the following:

```
points=[33,12,3,2,54,222,44,54] 
points=[54,32,1,1,33,44,54,21] 
points=[64,443,2,2,2,44,3,5]
```

This is my code:

```
public class Sample {
    private List<List<Integer>> matrix; //Getter and Setter Method 

    public List<List<Integer>> getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

    public Sample setMatrix(List<<Integer>> matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        return this; 
    }

    public void list_method(List<Integer> points) { 

        Sample sample = new Sample(); //Class object

        sample.getMatrix().add();

        System.out.println(sample);
    }
}
```

I got result like

```
matrix = [33,12,3,2,54,222,44,54]
matrix = [33,12,3,2,54,222,44,54 ,54,32,1,1,33,44,54,21] 
matrix =[33,12,3,2,54,222,44,54 ,54,32,1,1,33,44,54,21,64,443,2,2,2,44,3,5  ]
```

But I would like it to be in a form like :

```
matrix = [33,12,3,2,54,222,44,54]
matrix = [33,12,3,2,54,222,44,54], [54,32,1,1,33,44,54,21]
matrix = [33,12,3,2,54,222,44,54], [54,32,1,1,33,44,54,21], [64,443,2,2,2,44,3,5]
```

Comment: Try `List<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: show us sample class and sample.getMatrix.add() is not clear

Comment: Thanks for reply me i have tried like also i got above like ? my sample java class is private List<List<Integer>> matrix; public List<List<Integer>> getMatrix() {
        return matrix;}public Sample setMatrix(List<<Integer>> matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        return this;
    }

Comment: Adding this code in your question would be helpful.

Comment: I can't work out how you're getting the output you've specified. Is the `sample.getMatrix.add()` line correct? Surely you're using the `points` argument of that method somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In your `list_method`, you only need to write `matrix.add(points);`

And I don't know whether this is a typo, but `public Sample setMatrix(List<<Integer>> matrix) {` should be `public Sample setMatrix(List<List<Integer>> matrix) {`